# Ordem Crescente em uma lista encadeada em c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LISTA{

int dado;
struct LISTA *prox; 




}lista;

lista *insere(lista *p, int valor){

lista *novo;
novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
novo->dado = valor;
novo->prox = p;
return novo;

 }


void imprime(lista *p){
lista *novo;
for(novo = p; novo!= NULL; novo=novo->prox){
    printf("%d",novo->dado);

}


 }
 lista *ordemCrescente(lista *p){
lista *aux = NULL;
lista *novo = p;


int *recebe;
int x=0;
int menor=0;
while(novo != NULL){
    if(novo->dado < menor){
        aux = novo->prox;
         novo = novo->dado;
         novo->dado = aux; 
    return p;               
    }       

    novo= novo->prox;
}

     }






     main(){

  lista *l,i;
  lista *primeiro, *ultimo;
l = NULL;
l = insere(l, 20);
l = insere(l, 30);
l = insere(l, 40);
l = insere(l, 50);
l = insere(l, 60);


imprime(l);
printf("\n");
l = ordemCrescente(l);
imprime(teste);
  }
```

Comment: Esta função deveria fazer o que exatamente? Mostrar os elementos em ordem crescente? Porque se for, não há nenhum `printf` aí. O que ela parece estar tentando fazer (mas faz errado) é buscar o menor elemento na lista, mas o nome dela não indica isso. O que é que ela deveria fazer? Como e onde você está usando esta função?

Comment: Eu posso postar o código inteiro mas basicamente era pra ela colocar em ordem crescente oque já foi inserido na lista que é feito por outra função e também tem uma funcão print. O problema  é que a função esta errada.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vou começar com os problemas mais simples.

- Faltou um espaço após o `%d` na função `imprime`.
- Evite usar `l` ou `O` como nome de variáveis, pois é muito fácil confundir isso com os números `1` e `0`.
- Aprenda a identar adequadamente o seu código. Facilita muito a sua vida.

Agora vamos para o mais difícil. Observe isso:

```
        aux = novo->prox;
        novo = novo->dado;
        novo->dado = aux;
```

`novo` é um ponteiro. Ao fazer `novo->dado`, você vai pegar um inteiro e atribuir a um ponteiro (o seu compilador deve estar te dando uma *warning* por causa disso). Com isso, `novo` tornar-se-á um ponteiro inválido. Ao fazer `novo->dado = aux;`, o resultado é que você vai tentar acessar o endereço inválido e colocar alguma coisa lá. O resultado será uma falha de segmentação.

A forma correta de permutar `novo` e `novo->prox` seria assim:

```
        int aux = novo->dado;
        novo->dado = novo->prox->dado;
        novo->prox->dado = aux;
```

Apesar disso, o procedimento de organização como um todo está totalmente errado. O `return` dentro dele faria com que algo seja retornado na primeira "desinversão" de itens a ser feita, e não depois de todas terem sido feitas. Mesmo se não houvesse o `return`, o `while` percorre cada elemento da lista uma única vez (**O(n)**), e portanto é impossível que uma abordagem como essa sirva para ordenar a lista vez que a complexidade mínima possível é **O(n log n)**. Para piorar, qualquer abordagem baseada em varrer a lista e permutar elementos vizinhos vai ter obrigatoriamente desempenho mínimo **O(n²)**.

Assim sendo, não há nada na sua função `ordemCrescente` que seja aproveitável para uma boa solução. Ela teria que ser refeita do zero.

Sugiro estudar os algoritmos de ordenação existentes para entender como eles funcionam e então escolhe um deles para implementar. Dentre os que você pode tentar implementar com listas ligadas (use dois `while`s um dentro do outro para fazer isso), são o [Bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), o [Selection sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) e o [Insertion sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Todos eles terão complexidade **O(n²)** e todos eles têm como estratégia permutar elementos vizinhos diversas vezes até que a lista esteja ordenada.

Se quiser ir além e procurar algoritmos de ordenação mais eficientes mas que provavelmente não têm como ser implementados com listas ligadas (ao menos não de forma eficiente), você pode olhar o [Shell sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort) e o [Quick sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort), que embora ainda sejam **O(n²)** no pior caso, são **O(n log n)** no caso médio. Ou então olhar o [Heapsort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) e o [Merge sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) que têm complexidade **O(n log n)** em todos os casos.

Como bônus, há também o [Bogosort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) que é um dos algoritmos mais ineficientes já inventados. Falo sobre ele [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137194/132).